# Preg_replace_callback regex doesnt work correctly

Tags: php, regex

```
      $input = array("3.45Lt", "1.00€");
function kazkas($match){
    if($match[3]==="LTL"){
        $match[3] = "EUR";
    }
    elseif($match[3]==="Lt" | $match[3]==="LT" | $match[3]==="lT" |$match[3] === "lt"){
        $match[3] = "€";
    }else{
        $match[3]=$match[3];
    }
    $changeratio = 3.4488;
    return  number_format($matchn[1]/$changeratio,2).$match[2].$match[3];
    //3.4492
}
$result = preg_replace_callback('/(\d+[,.]?\d?)(\s?)(L+T+L?)/iD','kazkas',$input);
var_dump($result);
```

I want to find all numbers with LT or LTL and convert to euros also change currency logo.

Why preg_replace_callback doesnt take 3.45 ?r 
It take 3 than 45 and var_dump display this:

```
 array (size=2)
  0 => string '3.13.05â‚¬' (length=10)
  1 => string '1.00â‚¬' (length=7)
```

I tryed to test regex with preg_replace it return fine 3.45. What's wrong with preg_replace_callback. Is my regex bad?

Comment: Is the `$matchn[1]` typo in the original code or just a copying error here?

Comment: Your regexp only allows 1 digit after the decimal point, but your examples have 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is a little off.  Since you don't have the anchors `^` and `$`, the match can begin anywhere in the string.  What actually gets matched in the first example is just `45Lt`, which results in all kinds of problems for you.

You also have `$matchn[1]` instead of `$match[1]`, but that seems to just be a typo here.

```
/^(\d+[,.]?\d*)(\s?)(L+T+L?)$/i
```

I'm not sure that you need the `+` after `L` or `T` either.

Comment: Well in my program $match[1] was correct , i think i did copy/paste misstake. But the problem was in \d?. \d+ fixed it.

Comment: @DonatasVileita `\d+` requires decimal digits.  `\d*` allows 0 or more